# a list converted into select options by javascript for mobile, not working on IOS mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, ios, select, dropdown

I'm trying to create a select options with javascript for mobile, the data is coming from a list of links but it doesn't work only on IOS.

this is where the list is coming from links

```
var listSelect = document.querySelector(".epgtvm_select-country");   
var countries = document.querySelectorAll(".epgtvm_structure-container ol a");
```

and here is the entire function, but it doesn't work on IOS

```
function mobileCountries() {

  //create  the select element for the dropdown list before the ol
      var selectList = document.createElement("select");  
      selectList.setAttribute('data-selectconverted', 'true'); 
      listSelect.appendChild(selectList);


  var countries = document.querySelectorAll(".epgtvm_structure-container ol a");
  var countryOrder = [];

  //arrange country name and url in alphabetical order   
  countries.forEach(function(val) { //forEach for countries in <option>     
    countryOrder.push({
      'name': val.innerText,
      'url': val.href
    });
    countryOrder.sort(dynamicSort("name"));
    // return this;
  });

  //Create the option elements for the dropdown
  countryOrder.forEach(function(val) {
    var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
    //optionElement.innerHTML += val.name;  
    optionElement.innerText = val.name;
    optionElement.label = val.name;
    optionElement.value = val.url;
    selectList.appendChild(optionElement);
  });

  selectList.setAttribute('onblur', 'window.location = this.value;'); //onchange submit for the select
}
}
//DOM CONTENT READY
window.addEventListener("load", mobileCountries);
```

so the code takes all the links and create option elements inside a select tag, its working everywhere but in IOS, does anyone have a clue what could it be?

thank you

Comment: Which IOS browser?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to debug it? Are you getting any error messages in the console? When you say "not working" what exactly is happening?

Comment: on IOS mobile, doesn't work for any browser, Chrome nor firefox

Comment: on android, it displays the options of countries inside a select, but in IOS, the select is empty,

Comment: [blur compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Browser_compatibility) is unknown. It could be that.

Comment: You could check if `document.createElement` returns [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement). I would be very surprised if this is the case, but you never know.

Comment: also, your code snippet ends with a double `}}` which it shouldn't

Comment: You say select is empty in iOS: have you confirmed the select is created and appended to `listSelect`?  Can you tell if it has zero entries, or multiple entries with blank text?

Comment: running your code in the SO editor gives me "dynamicSort is not defined". where is dynamicSort coming from?

Comment: You sort the array after adding each element to it, rather than once all elements have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Option` constructor instead:

```
  // Create the option elements for the dropdown
  countryOrder.forEach(function(val) {
    selectList.appendChild(new Option(val.name, val.url));
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, same problem, it shows the list on android but not on IOS,

Comment: When and how do you set `listSelect`?

Comment: I have it at the beginning of the function
var listSelect = document.querySelector(".epgtvm_select-country");

Comment: hey I know it was some time ago but your answer helped me and worked! using the appendChild instead of the innerText

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU!! I know it was quite some time ago but yes! the appendchild worked instead of the innertext.

```
countryOrder.forEach(function(val){
    var optionElement = document.createElement("option");  
    optionElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val.name));      
    optionElement.value= val.url; 
    selectList.appendChild(optionElement);        
  });
```